# Import excel time into Pandas with decimal seconds

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, xlrd

I have an excel spread sheet (.xls) that contains a time column.  The time is displayed in Excel as minutes:seconds.tenths of seconds.  Such as "50:59.2" "50:59.4".  The raw data contains hours:minutes:seconds.decimalseconds.

When I import the data into pandas I am loosing the tenths of a second:

```
indata=pd.read_excel('Data.xls','Tabular Data',header=9,skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12])
indata['Time']
0     17:50:59
1     17:51:00
2     17:51:00
3     17:51:00
...
indata.Time[0].microsecond
0
indata.Time[1].microsecond
0
```

I also tried to use:  pd.ExcelFile() with xls.parse but got the same results.
Is there any way to control how Pandas parses the time from Excel?  It is getting it "correct" in terms of the hours, minutes and seconds, but it is dropping the tens, which I do need.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

As a test, I also just tried to use xlrd to directly read the data.  It does read in the time as floats, as expected.  But, if I then try to use xlrd.xldate_as_tuple() on some of the time data, I loose the fractions of a second.  While if I instead directly use datetime.timedelta(), I see the decimal seconds.
Perhaps the problem is that xlrd is dropping the data?

WORK AROUND:

I figured out a work around.  It doesn't solve the underlying problem, but it does allow me to read in the data.
I opened the spreadsheet in Excel and created a new column of time that is text-only based on the time (named Time_str):
=TEXT(A13,"h:mm:ss.0")
And saved it.  Then I was able to use pd.read_excel to read in the spreadsheet.
Finally, I converted this new column to a time in Pandas like this:
indata_t['Time2']=indata_t.Time_str.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%H:%M:%S.%f'))

Or, adding in a date like this:
indata_t['Time2']=indata_t.Time_str.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime('2009-01-11 '+x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
It is a kludge, but at least it let me import the data.

Comment: I see this in the documentation for `read_excel()`: `convert_float : boolean, default True
convert integral floats to int (i.e., 1.0 –> 1). If False, all numeric data will be read in as floats: Excel stores all numbers as floats internally.` So, you might try using `convert_float=False`

Comment: Good suggestion.  I just tried it, but it didn't change anything.  Still rounding decimal seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas used `xlrd` to read Excel files and the `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple()` function to get the date components to feed into `datetime.time()`.

However, `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple()` only returns seconds and not microseconds so that information is lost to `pandas`.

For example, say you have an Excel file like this (Number is the same as time but without a format):

```
Time            Number
0:17:51.000     0.012395833
0:17:51.200     0.012398148
0:17:51.400     0.012400463
0:17:51.600     0.012402778
0:17:52.800     0.012416667
0:17:53.000     0.012418981
```

Then, if you read the data with the following program:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('minutes.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

cell =  worksheet.cell(2,0)

# Print the A2 cell value as a number.
print cell.value

# Print the seconds part of the A2 cell value.
print (cell.value * (24*60*60)) % 60

# Print the xldate_as_tuple output.
print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(cell.value, workbook.datemode)
```

You get the following output:

```
0.0123981481481
51.2
(0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 51)
```

So, the decimal part of the seconds is read (51.2) but not returned by `xldate_as_tuple()` and thus not available to pandas.

This is [the documented behaviour](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xldate.py#L54) of `xldate_as_tuple()` but you could submit a [feature request or a pull request](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues).

**Update**: I [submitted a fix](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/pull/77) for this to xlrd.

Comment: This comment doesn't answer the question of how to import the decimal-seconds data.  It just verifies that the cause is Pandas using another library.  But, I did put in a feature request.