# Excel Data with HH:MM:SS format strip failing

Tags: python, excel, datetime

The excel file provided by a system I don't own is providing the number of hours worked on a project or task as HH:MM:SS and normally this would no be a problem if it were 23 hours or less.  Any time it is 24 hours or more python is seeing this as `1/1/1900 00:00:00` but the source file shows something like say `37:00:00`

I need to parse that field in the excel file to get the 37 as an int.

I tried the following:

```
df['Planned working time'].map(lambda x: (x, x.split(":"))) gives me 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'split'
```

`df['Planned working time'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%H:%M:%S"))` gives me time data `'1900-01-01 00:00:00'` does not match `format '%H:%M:%S`

Comment: `'%H:%M:%S'` is useless for any time calculation over 24 hours you might want to do, so the 1900 is irrelevant; it just makes sense to give it a year. You can always `strftime` it back to a time stamp at the end.

Comment: Relevant [import-excel-time-into-pandas-with-decimal-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004376/import-excel-time-into-pandas-with-decimal-seconds)

Comment: if it were a time stovfl I would agree that is relevant, but it's not a time field.

Answer (score 0):

Your `df['Planned working time']` contains data which is not in string format and therefore you will not be able to apply `.split()` and also does not match your `%H:%M:%S` format as there is also a date inside the Excel file (cell value).

You can try to lazily convert it into a string and get the first value from your splits.

```
df['Planned working time'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(x.split()[-1].split(':')[0]))
```

It removes the date, then gets the first element before `:` and converts it into an integer.

Comment: close, but in the case of an item that was 30:00:00 it is only picking up the 3.

Comment: That is weird, can you show me the value in the dataframe? So basically `int('30')` should be parsed as `30`.

Comment: there are 14K+ rows in the series.  I will try and isolate that row and show you.

Comment: If you are able to highlight that `30:00:00` is parsed as `3`, you should be able to just select that row or print its values.

Comment: actually I was wrong: `2462171 Task1 sdwived 6` is the output from your split.  the input is `2462171 Task1 sdwived 30:00:00`

Comment: That format is very different from what you have described, that is why there is an issue with the output. I would suggest you normalize the values in your input file and then run the comand

Comment: I don't have control over the input the file comes from a system out of my control and the request to change this format to remove this issue was denied.  It is exactly the format I said it is also.  Hours Minutes Seconds.  The problem is that it isn't a time; it is a duration and that is the thing that has caused me no small amount of problem.

Comment: I tested on your string you have provided and it returns `30`, are you sure that is it? I used, `int('2462171 Task1 sdwived 30:00:00'.split()[-1].split(':')[0])` which is basically same as the lambda function I have provided.

Comment: I can only tell you what is being spit out into the csv for sure, but let me try an if to print the output for that task

Comment: okay so here is the output if I just transfer the data to the csv without your split `1/1/1900 6:00` so it is taking the `30:00:00` and converting it to a datetime combo.  Even though it isn't.  So you split is working based on the data that pandas is providing it.  The underlying problem is that pandas is assuming that the data in that column is a time in 24 hour format and not just giving me the raw data for splitting.

Comment: So it doesn't seem to matter what I do or which module I use to read the data.  openpyxl shows the number_format as [hh]:mm and it translates that to the 1900-01-01.  Pandas sees similar things the minute it opens the file.  I don't know how to get at the data in the 30:00:00 format and strip just the beginning